# How to substr html entities properly?

Tags: php, html-entities

I have like this :

```
$mytext="that&#039;s really &quot;confusing&quot; and &lt;absolutly&gt; silly";
echo substr($mytext,0,6);
```

The output in this case will be : `that&#` instead of `that's`

What i want is to count html entities as 1 character then substr, because i always end up with breaked html or some obscure characters at the end of text.

Please don't suggest me to html decode it then substr then encode it, i want a clean method :)

Thanks

Comment: What is unclean about decoding and then taking a substr?  Would you rather do all sorts of fancy regexps or some kind of find-and-replace logic?  I'm not sure what kind of magic you are expecting to see.

Comment: PHP functions are there for some reason, don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. You can decode the HTML entities, `substr()` and then encode; or
2. You can use a regular expression.

(1) uses [`html_entity_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) and [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
$s = html_entity_decode($mytext);
$sub = substr($s, 0, 6);
echo htmlentities($sub);
```

(2) might be something like:

```
if (preg_match('!^([^&]|&(?:.*?;)){0,5}!s', $mytext, $match)) {
  echo $match[0];
}
```

What this is saying is: find me up to 5 occurrences of the preceding expression from the beginning of the string. The preceding expression is either:

- any character that isn't an ampersand; or
- an ampersand, followed by anything up to and including a semi-colon (ie an HTML entity).

This isn't perfect so I would favour (1).

Answer (score 3):

```
function encoded_substr($string, $param, $param2){
  $s = html_entity_decode($string);
  $sub = substr($s, $param, $param2);
  return htmlentities($sub);
}
```

There, I copypasted cletus' code into a function for you. Now you can call a very straightforward 3 line function with 1 line of code. If this isn't "clean" then I'm confused what "clean" means.

Answer (score 3):

Be advised that some characters break the proposed decoding + encoding, if you use `substr()`.

#### Example

```
$string=html_entity_decode("Workin&#8217; on my Fitness&#8230;In the Backyard.");

echo $string;
echo substr($string,0,25);
echo htmlentities(substr($string,0,25));
```

#### Will output:

- Workin’ on my Fitness…In the Backyard.
- Workin’ on my Fitness�
- (empty string)

#### The solution

Use [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php).

```
echo mb_substr($string,0,25);
echo htmlentities(mb_substr($string,0,25));
```

#### Will output:

- Workin’ on my Fitness…In
- Workin`&rsquo;` on my Fitness`&hellip;`In

Comment: This is the way to go! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try with following coding Functions.

```
<?php

$mytext="that&#039;s really &quot;confusing&quot; and &lt;absolutly&gt; silly";

echo limit_text($tamil_var,6);

function limit_text($text,$limit){
   preg_match_all("/&(.*)\;/U", $text, $pat_array);
   $additional=0;

   foreach ($pat_array[0] as $key => $value) {
     if($key <$limit){$additional += (strlen($value)-1);}
   }
   $limit+=$additional;

   if(strlen($text)>$limit){
     $text = substr( $text,0,$limit );
     $text = substr( $text,0,-(strlen(strrchr($text,' '))) );
   }
   return $text;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, clean method is only one: 
Not to use entities at all.
There are not a single reason to substr entitied string. It can be used to output only.
So, first substr, then encode.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correction for syntax error code, use mb_substr to avoid surprises like html entity having less characters, or character counting not working the way it should, in my case Sábado becoming Sá:

```
function encoded_substr($string, $param, $param2){
$s = html_entity_decode($string);
$sub = mb_substr($s, $param, $param2);
return htmlentities($sub);
}
```